# 'if' operator returning error if answer is 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an if statement:

```
<% if current_user.moderator? || user_is_authorized_for_topics? %>
```

that checks someone's role when they view a page. If they aren't either of these things, skip it. (`user_is_authorized` is defined in a separate controller).

As I was adding additional roles, I noticed that, if I'm not signed in (so no role), I receive the error:

```
undefined method `moderator?' for nil:NilClass
```

which I understand; if I run `moderator?` on a user without a role (or guest in this case too?), it would return `nil`.

In short: The issue (I think) is because it's reporting `nil` instead of `true` or `false`. But why doesn't it just skip this `if` statement when it comes back as anything besides `true`? I know `nil` is not `false`, but it also is not `true`.

Hoping someone can either tell me the cause of this, then maybe I can figure out a fix, or maybe someone can assist me with the error directly?  `moderator?` just calls the enum (admin, member, moderator).

Comment: the problem is that `current_user` is `nil` and your trying to call a method on a `nil` value

Comment: Right, so I understand why the error is happening. Perhaps I need more research about how 'if' works. To me, when it comes to an 'if' nil should be similar to -anything- besides true, right?

Comment: You aren't getting as far as "if nil". You're doing "if (nil.moderator?) and it fails trying to call moderator? on nil.

Comment: No, it's not that you're "run moderator? on a user without a role". It's that you're running #moderator? on no user at all.

Answer (score 2):

You get that error when you have no current_user. The function current_user returns Nil, and you are asking Nil whether it is a moderator. The error message is saying that you can't do that.

It's also not clear what provides the method "user_is_authorized_for_topics?". It probably should be the User object, but you aren't calling it that way - instead you're calling a global method or a helper. So in my answer, I'm going to assume that this method is on the User object where it should be.

Instead, you probably want something like this, which checks that you have a current_user first:

```
<% if current_user and current_user.moderator? || current_user.is_authorized_for_topics? %>
```

Note that I deliberately mixed "and" (low precedence) with "||" (higher precedence). That's not a style which is to everyone's taste, but I like it.

Comment: Your assumption it right, it's from a User Controller.
And your code worked perfectly. I didn't even think to make it identify current_user and THEN test their role. Thanks so much, that was much easier than I expected.

I'll need to research more about the cause of it. I understand from your explanation, but I guess I still don't understand why Nil.moderator? wouldn't return 'false'.

Comment: Here is the documentation for nil (which is the singleton instance of NilClass). Do you see a definition of a "moderator?" method there? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to this, which will make sure there is a user at all in the first place:

```
<% if current_user && (current_user.moderator? || user_is_authorized_for_topics?) %>
```